# Term to describe quality of one's day

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

I'm working on a sort of diary app with which users will rate different aspects of their day.  One of the metrics being measured is the overall quality of the user's day.  Currently I'm just calling this a "rating," but I don't think that's the best word to indicate what's being measured.  I just can't think of a better one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "quality"? If the answer is "that's a subjective assessment which the user must determine" then why not just call your metric "quality"? Without knowing exactly what you want it to mean (if anything), I don't see how you can get anything here apart from a list of different people's ideas about what *they* might wish to measure. Which could be *happiness, efficiency, profitability, simplicity,* etc. How do we know?

Comment: "How-was-my-day"

Comment: Just make sure the default selection is "Whiling away the empty hours until death"

Comment: A _rating_ implies a single dimension. But day quality is multidimensional. Good busy days, bad busy days, good slow days, bad slow days.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is really the predicament.  I'm trying to avoid a word like rating because I don't think it's a good UX decision, but anything I can think of to replace it seems like it will sort of steer them into a more specific answer than I'd like.

Comment: @Neil The rating metric will be the one default measurement.  Ideally the user will then add other things they deem worth tracking, like anxiety level, amount of sleep, etc.

Comment: @Eric: Assuming it doesn't make any difference to your app exactly what the "rating" value *means*, why not provide support for several of them? With "default" names like *enjoyability, efficiency, profitability, completeness*, or whatever, but allowing the user to change the names if he has some other attribute he would like to record.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The "rating" is meant to be the high(est) level assessment of the user's day.  It is the default tracked item and they have the option to add other items to track.  To give more background, this is for bipolar disorder patients to be able to track anything they think should be monitored.  For some people this is may be depression, others may not have that issue but want to keep track of their anxiety level.  The real value of the app is in the ability to keep track of things that _you_ need to keep track of.  Rating is just default metric so that the app works "out of the box."

Comment: @Eric: That suggests ***importance*** might be what you want to call one of them by default. But you could still have more than one - for example, the "patient" might rate each day according to how well or badly any actions taken to stabilise mood worked, so ***success/effectiveness*** might be another useful metric. But I think if you can't describe *exactly* what you want the metric to "quantify", you're effectively asking ELU to do your application "requirements spec", which starts to look Off Topic to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question was regarding a better word choice than rating in the context, which I think is on topic. What I want it to quantify is the general quality of someones day, a sort of umbrella over the other optional metrics. That said, this has definitely evolved into a UX discussion and I think my original question was based on some poor UX assumptions.  Feel free to close the question or add an answer that I can accept.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: All I'm saying is you seem to be asking for a "better" word than ***rating*** - with no clear indication of why that's not suitable, or what *specifically* you want the target word to embody that's not conveyed by your original word.

Answer (score 2):

Goodness! That should've been easy.

The word's primary sense fits the purpose well, and as a bonus it also has several nice secondary meanings.

***[good·ness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goodness)***  (go͝od′nĭs)
*n*. **1**. The state or quality of being good.

Englund et al., ispsychophysics.org [[pdf](http://www.ispsychophysics.org/fd/index.php/proceedings/article/viewFile/126/121), 388kB]

> Participants also rated their general opinion on the stimuli in each pair, that is, the **goodness** of the stimuli. The results showed that the sign and magnitude of the order effect depended on the **goodness level** of the stimuli.

There's also the interesting usage as a [Six Sigma Metric](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=leQvoUXM9L0C&pg=PA12&lpg=PA1157&dq=define%20%22goodness%20level%22&source=bl&ots=w1ojWtYy-L&sig=WDPlIB55EY8SrmiUK9wgX3C48Kk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7d0rU6LQHfCuiQf2goCgAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=define%20%22goodness%20level%22&f=false).

The "goodness level" shows how good the day has been.

Answer (score 1):

How about any one or more of the following:

- In one word, how would you characterize your day?
- A one-word label for your day.
- A one-word adjective for your day (e.g., crappy, delightful, boring, exciting, normal, confusing, frustrating, busy, slow, endless, positive, productive, interesting, hellish, best, worst).
- The single-best word to summarize your day.
- Overall evaluation of your day in one word.
- Overall characterization of your day.
- Rank your day on a scale of 1 to 10, with 1 being abysmal, and 10 being splendiferous. (Or simply, "ranking.")
- Your day's ranking, using the following scale: good, better, best; or productive, unproductive, a complete waste of time.
- Your day in one word.
- Encapsulation
- Abstract
- Condensation
- Précis
- Label
- Descriptor

Comment: I'm not asking them to describe or rate their day with a one word response.  I'm looking for a one word label of sorts for the rating of their day on a scale of 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

How about **"happiness index"**

or **"mood spectrum"** assuming the mood is the outcome of the quality of the day ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Inverse level of annyoyedness
2. retrospective bliss indicator
3. past perceived happiness indicator
4. lack of staying in the present moment indicator.
5. funness indicator
6. lack of silly inverse indicator
7. perceived progress indicator
8. anything else
9. amount of energy wasted on being productive
10. colour of your glasses indicator (rose, black/white/, etc.)

Comment: Very wordy, but that was at the heart of your humor (or humour), yes?

Comment: yes humor some like to call it